# How to implement double indexing in a 2D sparse scipy matrix?

Tags: python, indexing, scipy, sparse-matrix

Suppose I have a 2D sparse matrix M representing the results of 2-on-2 basketball matches. 
I want to use address the elements of the matrix using double-indexing :
Element M[i,j][k,l] will represent the score of the game played by a team of players i and j against team  k and l. Thus, each column/row is specified by two numbers instead of one. 
Note that this is not a 4D matrix. 
I'm looking for a way to do this with a sparse SciPy matrix in order to be able to perform various matrix-related calculations (eigenvalues/vectors, etc).